# Configuring remote desktop on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-7, remote-desktop, remote-access

I’m trying to connect over internet to my home workstation (Windows Server 2008 R2 Web Edition) from my PC at work (Windows 7) via remote desktop.

I configured the workstation to accept remote desktop and I can connect to it from my laptop if I’m connected to the LAN at home. However, I can’t connect from my PC at work.

My question is: Is possible to connect to my workstation over internet using remote desktop? Is there any step by step resource to set this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- you should first activate it here: Control Panel \ System \ Remote.
- Activate the Allow users to connect remotely to this computer.
- Make sure that there is no firewall rule to blok the connction to your server on port 3389 from outside...

Comment: @qxxx: would you be more specific? I already configure windows server to allow remote desktop and assigned the user who will connect; in fact already can connect vi remote desktop but only within local LAN connection not over internet.

Comment: @Abdullah if you cannot connect over the internet then you need to look at your router and check that port forwarding is configured correctly to forward traffic for port 3389 to your server.

Comment: Also remember that your workplace may be blocking outbound connections on port 3389 (and others).

Comment: Thank you all.. that was the router settings prevent incoming connection to port 3389, Fixed by configure the router to allow connection to 3389. all works fine now

Answer (score 0):

As qxxx said, check to make sure that your firewall (dsl router, cable modem, etc.) is not blocking port 3389.  I have used http://canyouseeme.org/ in the past.

Comment: @Frnak Perez: Thank you. The link to "canyouseeme.org" was very useful

Answer (score 0):

I have to think your first hurdle is getting external access to that internal machine. I'm assuming you have a cable modem or DSL router serving up DHCP to your internal computers with an internal IP? If yes, you either need to determine the external IP of your router and forward the port to the correct internal machine and then connect via that external IP when away from home or maybe look at a dynamic DNS config.